# Tracking Digital Assets in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to build out a feature that will let the content authors know if a particular asset (e.g. an Image or a video under site assets library) is being referenced by any content(Pages) in the sharepoint site.

Is there any built-in feature that can assist in that?

If not, do you have any suggestions on how should I go about it?

Thanks,
Krantz

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of any OOB features to do this at the moment, but off of the top of my head, here is how I would go about it.

Develop a timer job to traverse your site content, going through each and every object, checking for references to each of the assets' unique IDs. I would then store that reference in a list specifically made for this data. Now, it's as simple as manipulating the list through either custom views or maybe something code-based to be able to display/work with the data how you want.

This would obviously not be real-time, but it would basically mimic a very rudimentary indexing functionality and shouldn't be too complicated if you are familiar with the object model from a coding standpoint.